# How do I pull <p> tags without attributes using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Say a web page contains the following:

```
<p style="display: none;"><input id="ak_js" name="ak_js" type="hidden" value="68"/></p>

<p><b>Lack of sales.. ANY sales.</b></p>
```

I'm trying to write code that would pull only the second tag. Basically all paragraph tags that don't contain attributes. 
I tried the following two pieces of code below, but they don't get me the results I want.

```
text = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

for tag in text.find_all("p", attrs = False):
    .....

for tag in text.find_all(re.compile("^<p>$")):
    ....
```

What's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give a lambda to `find_all` and filter with it.

```
soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'p' and not tag.attrs)
```

Comment: `findAll` is deprecated... OP should continue to use `find_all`